# How to inner join with PyODBC

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

**UPDATE** I updated my code and the error I am receiving.

I'm not exactly sure how to use `INNER JOIN` with Python's pypyODBC.

I am getting an error that says

> "Cannot find either column "UT" or the user-defined function or aggregate,  "UT.userID", or the name is ambigous."

I've tried specifying the table in the SELECT statement.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

```
import pypyodbc

def intercard():

    firstname = "Paul"
    key = "334" 

    try:
        connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=MyServerName;Database=MyDatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
    except pypyodbc.Error as ex:
        sqlstate = ex.args[0]
        if sqlstate == '28000':
            print("You do not have access.") 
    cursor = connection.cursor() 
    SQLCommand = ("SELECT UT.userID, Status, userName "      
        "FROM dbo.StatusTable as ST INNER JOIN dbo.UserTable as UT "   # table name
        "ON ST.userID=UT.userID"
        "(nolock)"
        "WHERE userKey LIKE ? AND First Name LIKE ?")
    Values = ['%' + key + '%', '%' + firstname + '%']
    cursor.execute(SQLCommand,Values)
    results = cursor.fetchone()
    if results:
        print(connections + " " + str(results[0]) + " " + str(results[1])) # enters results in entry
        connection.close()
```

I just want to connect to both the *StatusTable* and *UserTable*.

** UPDATE 2 **

I can run the below directly in SQL Server and it works.  But I can't get it working in Python...

```
SELECT ST.[userID]

  FROM [dbo].[StatusTable] as ST INNER JOIN [dbo].[UserTable] as UT
  ON ST.userID = UT.userID

  where Name = 'Paul'
```

Comment: @Kade - You are defining your table aliases as `ST` and `UT` in the FROM clause and then you are using `SE` and `SP` as the aliases in your ON clause.

Comment: Fixed.  I hadn't updated those yet.

Comment: @Kade - It looks like you need a space after `as UT`. Always put a space at the end of each code fragment to prevent unexpected errors when the fragments are glued together.

Answer (score 2):

Since your edit history indicates multiple updates, below is a list addressing your overall SQL syntax issues.

1. In SQL Server, `INNER JOIN` must be paired with an `ON` clause. Your very first version did not do so. `CROSS JOIN` are the only joins that do not need `ON` clauses and SQL Server's specific `CROSS APPLY` or `OUTER APPLY`.
2. Table aliases used in `FROM` or `JOIN` clauses must be maintained in all other clauses: `SELECT`, `WHERE`, or `GROUP BY`. Either stick to *ST* and *UT* or *SE* and *SP* namings but maintain their usage. Do not prefix column identifiers if they are not defined elsewhere.
3. Column identifiers with names and special characters as well as [reserved words](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql) should be escaped. In SQL Server, you can escape with square brackets. Hence, *First Name* column with its space requires escaping and should read:

   ```sql
   WHERE userKey LIKE ? AND [First Name] LIKE ?
   ```
4. Because SQL requires proper punctuation and spaces in its grammar, consider using Python's triple-quote multi-line block for long strings like SQL statements:

   ```
   SQLCommand = """SELECT UT.userID, ST.Status, UT.userName      
                   FROM dbo.StatusTable as ST (nolock)
                   INNER JOIN dbo.UserTable as UT (nolock)
                     ON ST.userID = UT.userID
                   WHERE UT.userKey LIKE ? AND UT.[First Name] LIKE ?"""
   ```
5. As a final note, none of your issues here is due to Python or `pypyodbc` which interface to your SQL Server database. All such errors are being raised by the MSSQL engine due to syntax issues. These same items would fail in other ODBC (i.e., VBA's ADO or R's RODBC) or non-ODBC (i.e., Java's JDBC or Python's `pymssql`) connections.

   The bottom SQL query that works is substantively different than the one being attempted inside Python such as no spaces between clauses `UT.userID(nolock)WHERE`, no use of *First Name*, and no misuse of table aliases.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the join- what columns are you joining? For example, if StatusTable and UserTable both have a userID column, your command would update to

```
SELECT Status, userName     
        FROM dbo.StatusTable as ST INNER JOIN dbo.UserTable  as UT
        ON ST.userId=UT.userID
        (nolock)
        WHERE userKey LIKE ? AND First Name LIKE ?
```

Comment: There actually is a userID column in both tables.  When I do the above, I get "The multi-part indentifier "SE.userID could not be found"

Comment: Where is *SE* used in this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Nolock was in the wrong place.